# Wso2 API Manager Active Active deployment clustering

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am trying to do active active deployment and went through the guide https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+an+Active-Active+Deployment

My question if I want to maintain two manager nodes how do I sync the server directory because in the tutorial mentioned above one is manager and other is worker so using rsync we can sync the directory

But for both manager instances how to sync up directories

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't have active-active manager nodes. They should be active-passive.

Comment: Hi bhathiya thanks for the reply, in active passive deployment if active goes down and publisher publish in passive mode how to sync up with active node ?

Comment: what do you mean by `publish in passive mode`?

Comment: I mean to say when server1 is in active the API published synapse store in server1 directory which will be sync to server2(passive) using rsync.but when server1 is down and API published in server2 how to sync those API synapse files back to server 1 ?

Comment: I haven't tried rSync myself yet. In svn dep-sync (old method) what usually did was making both managers `commit=true`. In that way, both commits whenever they get a new file. But since the setup is active-passive, only one gets files at a time. You should be able to do the same in rSync too.

Comment: It was mentioned to point both the nodes to same gateway endpoint so in that case if I point both the nodes to gateway of node1 and if that node1 goes down API can't be published from node 2 right ?

Comment: Configure the API Publisher of both nodes to publish to the Gateway of one of the nodes by pointing the <ServerURL> to the same Gateway node. It's der in step 12 in https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+an+Active-Passive+Deployment

Comment: Yes, you can use the loadbalance endpoint of gateway instead. But that works only if rSync can achieve 2 way syncing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer bhathiya in https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+rsync+for+Deployment+Synchronization they mentioned that manager node can't be scalable.so can we come to a conclusion that publisher module can be present only in one manager node using rsync